# PHP Ignoring all but last array element

Tags: php, arrays

I'm playing around with a basic PHP site just for my own knowledge and I basically have a text file filled with "passwords". I've opened this text file as an array into my page, but when I search for a specific element, the only password that shows as valid is the last option, and it seems to ignore every other element in the array.

So if my password list is

> passwords
>
> 12345
>
> test
>
> qwerty

When I search for the first 3 elements, it says that it does not exist in the array. However, if I searched for the last value, which is 'qwerty' here, it will match.

```
<?php
$file = explode("\n", file_get_contents("passwords.txt"));


//Call the function and pass in the list
if (isset($_POST['submit_login'])) {

    //Set the search variable
    $search = $_POST['password'];

    search_array($file, $search);
} else {
    //echo "You did not search! <br />";
    //echo "<a href='searchForm.html'>Try again?</a>";
}

function search_array($array_value, $search_query)
{
    echo "<span><h4>The Array List: </h4><span/>";
    foreach ($array_value as $key => $value) {
        echo $key." ";
        echo $value."<br />";


     }
    if ($value == $search_query) {
        echo "<h5>Search Stuff</h5>";
        echo "You searched for: " . $search_query . "</br>";
        echo "Your search was found in the index #" .$key. "<br />";


    } else {
        echo "You searched for: " . $search_query . "</br>";
        echo "Your search did not match any of the items. <br />";
        echo "<a href='searchForm.html'>Try again?</a>";
    }


}


?>
```

However, if I searched for '12345' for example, which is index 1 in the array, I will get the output

> You searched for: 12345
>
> Your search did not match any of the items.

But, searching for 'qwerty' which is the last element yields the desired response.

Comment: Your code makes no sense you just loop through the array! You don't have your code in the loop

Comment: your if loop is out of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make everything so complicated, just use this:

(Here I first read your file with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then just simply use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to see if the value is in the array and also get the key)

```
<?php

    $lines = file("passwords.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)

    //Call the function and pass in the list
    if (isset($_POST['submit_login'])) {

        //Set the search variable
        $search = $_POST['password'];
        search_array($lines, $search);

    } else {
        //echo "You did not search! <br />";
        //echo "<a href='searchForm.html'>Try again?</a>";
    }

    function search_array($array_value, $search_query) {
        echo "<span><h4>The Array List: </h4><span/>";

        if(($key = array_search($search_query, $array_value)) !== FALSE) {
            echo "<h5>Search Stuff</h5>";
            echo "You searched for: " . $search_query . "</br>";
            echo "Your search was found in the index #" .$key. "<br />";
        } else {
            echo "You searched for: " . $search_query . "</br>";
            echo "Your search did not match any of the items. <br />";
            echo "<a href='searchForm.html'>Try again?</a>";
        }

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your `if ($value == $search_query)` not inside foreach loop. Move closing bracket for foreach below if-else blocks and it should work.

Comment: This does not work as well.
It loops through each value saying that it does not match each value.

Comment: @JessieChaisson well, it should at least for one say that it matches, if you want echo only once, this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29394046/4712360 answer should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your "search_array" method to this.

```
function search_array($array_value, $search_query)
{
    echo "<span><h4>The Array List: </h4><span/>";
    $match = false;
    foreach ($array_value as $key => $value) {
        echo $key." ";
        echo $value."<br />";

        if ($value == $search_query) {
           $match = true;
           break;
        }
     }
    if ($match) {
        echo "<h5>Search Stuff</h5>";
        echo "You searched for: " . $search_query . "</br>";
        echo "Your search was found in the index #" .$key. "<br />";
    } else {
        echo "You searched for: " . $search_query . "</br>";
        echo "Your search did not match any of the items. <br />";
        echo "<a href='searchForm.html'>Try again?</a>";
    }
}
```

The password check should be inside the foreach loop and after the check you can print some stuff.